# Python call object function from user input

Tags: python, function, oop

I got a question of how I can call a function of an object. 
Here is how I can call a function with userinput:

```
Player1 = Player()
Player2 = Player()

INPUT = input()
if INPUT in locals().keys():
            try:
                print(locals()[INPUT]())
```

but I want to call for example `Player1.status()` (You dont need to know what it does, I just want to call it)
It doesnt work and I know why it doesnt work but how does it work? 
And calling `Player1` makes no sense obviously.

Comment: Use an explicit `dict` or `list` instead of individually numbered variables and `locals()`.

Comment: But `"It doesnt work"` is not a good description of the symptoms. Also, you should break down your last line into separate concepts so you can tell what you mean.

Comment: The *user* of your program should not need to know the name of the method it wants to call. The mapping between the user's input and the method it will trigger should be in your code, not your user's head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [getattr(object, name[, default])](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/getattr) like this:

```
class Player:
    def status(self):
        return "Active"

player1 = Player()
INPUT = 'player1.status'

input_list = INPUT.split('.')

method_to_call = locals()[input_list[0]]
for i in input_list[1:]:
    method_to_call = getattr(method_to_call, i)

method_to_call()
```

Comment: I think the input indicates which object to use, not which method on an object.

Comment: @chepner Just fixed it.